# How to use useEffect and for loop to generate multiple JSX elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, jsx, use-effect

I want to use useEffect and for-loop to generate multiple JSX elements but nothing is rendered in this case.

warning code: "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'renderInfoCard'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import InfoCard from '../components/InfoCard.jsx';
import { getScenicSpotRequest } from '../request test.js';

function MainScreen() {

  const [renderInfoCard, setRenderInfoCard] = useState(null);
  const [renderInfoCardArray, setRenderInfoCardArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //data recieve from axios request
    getScenicSpotRequest().then(result => {
    //want to use useEffect and for loop to generate multiple JSX elements 
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        setRenderInfoCard(<InfoCard Name={result[i].Name} Description={result[i].Description} Picture={result[i].Picture.PictureUrl1} />);
        setRenderInfoCardArray[i] += renderInfoCard;
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Navbar NavbarTitle="ScenicSpot" />
        {renderInfoCardArray}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainScreen;
```

Comment: Have you tried by adding missing dependencies as in the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't put components in state (and you really shouldn't mutate state either). Instead, wait for all the results to come back, then set the state with *all* of the results at once. When returning the JSX, *then* you can create the components by mapping over the results (if they exist).

```
function MainScreen() {
  const [sceneResults, setSceneResults] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getScenicSpotRequest()
      .then(setSceneResults);
      // .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this - don't want unhandled rejections
  }, [setSceneResults]); // this will not change, so it's safe to put in the dependency array
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Navbar NavbarTitle="ScenicSpot" />
        {sceneResults.map(result => (
          <InfoCard Name={result.Name} Description={result.Description} Picture={result.Picture.PictureUrl1} />)
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I put the `setSceneResults` into the effect dependency array to satisfy the linter, but that's OK, the reference to the state setter is stable, so it'll only run on mount.

Comment: lmaoo i was just about to finish typing this xD

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the state to store the Elements, use the state to store the request value then `map` through those values to render

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import InfoCard from '../components/InfoCard.jsx';
import { getScenicSpotRequest } from '../request test.js';

function MainScreen() {

  const [infoCards, setInfoCards] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    //data recieve from axios request
    getScenicSpotRequest().then(result => setInfoCards(result));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Navbar NavbarTitle="ScenicSpot" />
        {infoCards.map(infoCard => (<InfoCard key={infoCard.Id} Name={infoCard.Name} Description={infoCard.Description} Picture={infoCard.Picture.PictureUrl1} />))}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainScreen;
```

Comment: Your answer works when  `getScenicSpotRequest().then(setInfoCards);` write as `getScenicSpotRequest().then(result => setInfoCards(result));` thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using @CertainPerformance 's answer, it will pop up a warning which is "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key".

To solve this problem, I added key={infoCard.ID} inside the JSX

```
function MainScreen() {

  const [sceneResults, setSceneResults] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getScenicSpotRequest().then(setSceneResults);
  }, [setSceneResults]); 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Navbar NavbarTitle="ScenicSpot" />
        {sceneResults.map((infoCard) => (<InfoCard key={infoCard.ID} Name={infoCard.Name} Description={infoCard.Description} Picture={infoCard.Picture.PictureUrl1} />))}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainScreen;
```